# iOS: Is buffering possible in Live Streaming (HLS)

Tags: ios, iphone, streaming, avplayer, ios10

Is that any possibility to buffer Live Streaming?

I searched a lot but didn't get any official answer. Different people have different views on this.

Many people told that It is open from ios 10 , but did not get this.

Some have answered that use caching proxy, but I did not understand this.

**Thanks for your valuable time**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to cache HLS segments with AVPlayer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434682/is-it-possible-to-cache-hls-segments-with-avplayer)

Comment: @Dev-iL, Caching is different than buffering. pls check it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll share a good answer i found.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36538295/2037169

To sum it up. this is wwdc 2016 on how to work with HLS from ios 10.
i did a poc today using this example it works great.

im currently looking into how to use HLS in tvOS. 
the AVFoundation class they used in the example seem to apply to ios only

NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED
AVAssetDownloadTask : NSURLSessionTask

Comment: It is for caching , not for buffering.