# Can we manually download/cache the transport stream while streaming m3u8 file

Tags: ios, swift, gcdwebserver

I am trying to play transport stream from m3u8 file. My requirement is to process the downloaded data before giving it to AVPlayer. For that I am using a proxy server[GCDWebserver] to intercept all the request. In proxy server I will download the data process it and feed it back.

I was able to download the media file and also have tried returning data using  GCDWebServerDataResponse(data: apiData, contentType: apiResponse.mimeType ?? ""). But player is not playing the media content.

1. I am using GCDWebserver as my proxy server.
2. I have created an instance of AVPlayerItem with the following url
   http://34.55.7.151:8080/
   which is actually my local servers ip & port number.

   ///  Initialise AVPlayer Item

   ```
   let url = URL(string: "http://10.155.177.151:8080/")!
   let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
   player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
   player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false

   let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
   playerViewController.player = player

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
           playerViewController.player!.play()
       }
   }
   ```

///     Http proxy handler

```
    webServer.addDefaultHandler(forMethod: "GET", request: GCDWebServerRequest.self) { (request, completion) in

        let  mediaUrl = URL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!

        if self.session == nil {
            self.session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        }

        let dataTask = self.session?.dataTask(with: mediaUrl, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let apiData = data, let apiResponse = response {
                completion(GCDWebServerDataResponse(data: apiData, contentType: apiResponse.mimeType ?? ""))
            } else {
                completion(GCDWebServerDataResponse(text: "Error"))
            }
        })
        dataTask!.resume()
    }
```

Comment: It looks like a duplicate of [Is it possible to cache HLS segments with AVPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434682/is-it-possible-to-cache-hls-segments-with-avplayer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar has been implemented here: https://github.com/StyleShare/HLSCachingReverseProxyServer

It downloads the segments while streaming, if the segment is available locally, it will use that instead.